# Retrieve HTTP response headers from WKWebview

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

I need to read the response HTTP headers from a `WKWebview`'s request. I need to perform customizations based on certain custom headers sent by the server. It's not possible to add this information in the response data.

I could not find any entry in the documentation nor in previous questions here.  Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks like you can access the response from the `WKNavigationDelegate` method [`webView:decidePolicyFor:decisionHandler:`](//developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455643-webview).

Set some object as the `WKWebView`'s `navigationDelegate`, and add this method:

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationResponse:(WKNavigationResponse *)navigationResponse decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationResponsePolicy))decisionHandler {
    NSDictionary *headers = ((NSHTTPURLResponse *)navigationResponse.response).allHeaderFields;

    decisionHandler(WKNavigationResponsePolicyAllow);
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Swift 3.1, 4, and 5 version of NobodyNada's answer:

Without force cast

```swift
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void) {
    if let response = navigationResponse.response as? HTTPURLResponse {
        let headers = response.allHeaderFields
        //do something with headers
    }
    decisionHandler(.allow)
}
```

With force cast:

```swift
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void) {
    let headers = (navigationResponse.response as! HTTPURLResponse).allHeaderFields
    //do something with headers 
    decisionHandler(.allow)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Swift 4.2 Answers with response.
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void)
 {
   let response = navigationResponse.response as? HTTPURLResponse
       decisionHandler(.allow)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the delegate method you can retrieve the `(WKNavigationResponse*)navigationResponse`. And from the navigationResponse object you can get the response itself:

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationResponse:(WKNavigationResponse *)navigationResponse decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationResponsePolicy))decisionHandler {

     NSHTTPURLResponse * response = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)navigationResponse.response;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5

```
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse) async -> WKNavigationResponsePolicy {
        let URLResponse = navigationResponse.response as? HTTPURLResponse
        URLResponse?.allHeaderFields.forEach({ key, value in
            print("decidePolicyFor key: ", key)
            print("decidePolicyFor value: ", value)
        })

    
        return .allow
    }
```